# Determine whether a user is following me via SoundCloud API

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I'm creating a webapp gathering stats from SoundCloud.

I would like to determine whether a user (I've got the ID) is following me or not.
All that I can do so far is parse me/followers page-by-page over and over again.

I think this is quite cumbersome. Is there a better way to achieve this?
SoundCloud itself can manage it and you're using the API as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `/users/{TheirUserId}/followings/{MyUserId}` URI. This will then return a User object (yours) if they are following or a HTTP 404 if they're not.